# Multiple FAQ pages using FAQ module

Tags: views, 7

I am using the FAQ module in drupal7. My website has many pages which should have a FAQ of their own. So adding FAQ from "Add Content" adds and lists all the FAQs in different categories in the "faq-page". For example, I have two applications so i need dedicated faq page for application 1 and 2.

Is this possible using the FAQ module ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the FAQ module provides the ability to have separate categories of FAQ via the taxonomy module as per the project page:

> "In addition, if the 'Taxonomy' module is enabled, it is possible to
>   put the questions into different categories when editing. Users will
>   need the 'view faq page' permission to view the built-in 'faq' page
>   and will need the 'administer faq' permission to configure the layout,
>   etc."

To use the individual faq categories, use the urls: faq-page/[tid] - where the [tid] is the term ID of the category you want.

You can also use views to make additional faq pages for specific categories if you like.

Comment: how can i make additional faq pages ? I have made categories in which i classify questions of a particular topic. But they all show up in the "faq-page".

Comment: Just updated my answer. The url is faq-page/[tid] where [tid] is the term id of the category you want to view.

Comment: I am using the collapsible Q&A. If i have to link to another answer in one answer then how can i do that? For example i write in answer 2.4 to refer to answer 1.2, then how can i do that? any ideas?

Comment: (hope this makes sense) If you hover over the link for the answer you want to link to it should be a url with a hash and then some more text after the hash. This is the link to that answer. If you create another link the same it should work.

Comment: edited my previous answer

Comment: but as in my example the question 1.2 is a node but i want the link to open the question in the same page.